# How to reduce the number of executions with xargs -I

Tags: xargs

The `find` command has two ways to execute something in an `xargs` style.

```
find foo -exec bar '{}' baz ';'
find foo -exec bar '{}' baz '+'
```

The difference between them is that the first will execute once per found file the second will group the files to reduce the number of executions.

When I look at `xargs` it has the `-I` switch eg:

```
xargs -I{} foo bar {} baz
```

This will execute once per arg.

**Question:**
Is there a way to reduce the number of executions in `xargs` as there is in `find`?

I want to do something like this:

```
xargs -I{} echo start {} end << EOF
hello
world
EOF
```

And get the result:

```
start hello world end
```

NOT:

```
start hello end
start world end
```

Comment: Do you mean `-n`?

Comment: Note that `find foo -exec bar '{}' baz '+'` won’t work, the `{}` has to be the last argument with `+`.

Comment: @pfnuesel If you can show how to put that with the command above to make it work I'll accept.  All experiments I've done with it so far have failed.

Comment: @StephenKitt Can't think why I've never hit that before.  The fact that find can't do it hints that xargs can't either.

Comment: Yes, exactly, for the same reasons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to make a simple wrapper script for your command:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo start "$@" end
```

then you can use `xargs echo-wrapper`

Of course, you can do that inline:

```
xargs sh -c 'echo start "$@" end' sh <<EOF
hello 
world
EOF
```

Do note the extra `sh` at the end there—that's part of the `sh -c` syntax, it specifies `$0` inside the shell.

Comment: What about a function?

Comment: bonus points for the one liner.  The context of this is that I'm kicking something off via ssh, piping a local file in as args of a remote command.  The one liner is perfect because I don't want to put scripts on the remote machine.

Comment: @tomas xargs isn't a shell builtin, so AFAIK it can't call shell functions.

Comment: @couling Be careful with the quoting. Can be a royal PITA with ssh.

Comment: @derobert thanks.  Yes I wanted to avoid the `sh -c` for that reason, but I don't think I'll get away with it.